# Trouble with Microsoft Edge, Protractor and Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, microsoft-edge

I am facing some trouble using Protractor, Jasmine and Open Sauce to test an Angular 2 app.

I'd just like to make a basic series of tests like showed below. The tests succeed on every platform except on Microsoft Edge.

Here are the simple tests:

app.po.ts file :

```
import { browser, element, by } from 'protractor';

export class BookreaderPage {
    navigateTo() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        return browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
    }

    getParagraphText() {
        return element(by.css('app-root h1')).getText();
    }

    getBannerTitle() {
        return element(by.css('app-root app-banner h1')).getText();
    }

    getBannerText() {
        return element(by.css('app-root app-banner p')).getText();
    }

}
```

app.e2e-spec.ts file :

```
import { BookreaderPage } from './app.po';

describe('bookreader App', () => {
    let page: BookreaderPage;

    beforeEach(() => {
        page = new BookreaderPage();
    });

    it('should display message saying app works', () => {
        page.navigateTo();
        expect(page.getParagraphText()).toEqual('APP WORKS!');
    });

    it('should display message saying banner title', () => {
        page.navigateTo();
        expect(page.getBannerTitle()).toEqual('BANNER TITLE');
    });

    it('should display message saying banner works', () => {
        page.navigateTo();
        expect(page.getBannerText()).toEqual('banner works!');
    });

});
```

When these tests are executed on Edge, the elements seem to be found but the equalities don't match. For example, with Chrome, I get the following result:

```
[04:29:40] I/testLogger - [chrome Windows 10 #31-0] PID: 8245
[chrome Windows 10 #31-0] Specs: /home/travis/build/[secure]/bookreader/dist/out-tsc-e2e/app.e2e-spec.js
[chrome Windows 10 #31-0] 
[chrome Windows 10 #31-0] [04:28:52] I/sauce - Using SauceLabs selenium server at https://ondemand.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub
[chrome Windows 10 #31-0] Spec started
[chrome Windows 10 #31-0] [04:29:37] W/element - more than one element found for locator By(css selector, app-root h1) - the first result will be used
[chrome Windows 10 #31-0] 
[chrome Windows 10 #31-0]   bookreader App
[chrome Windows 10 #31-0]     ✓ should display message saying app works
[chrome Windows 10 #31-0]     ✓ should display message saying banner title
[chrome Windows 10 #31-0]     ✓ should display message saying banner works
[chrome Windows 10 #31-0] 
[chrome Windows 10 #31-0] Executed 3 of 3 specs SUCCESS in 3 secs.
[chrome Windows 10 #31-0] [04:29:39] I/sauce - SauceLabs results available at http://saucelabs.com/jobs/a377e39ebb074ad490b048df2a4cffb8
```

But with Microsoft Edge, I get the following errors:

```
[04:29:43] I/testLogger - [MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] PID: 8275
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] Specs: /home/travis/build/[secure]/bookreader/dist/out-tsc-e2e/app.e2e-spec.js
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] 
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] [04:28:52] I/sauce - Using SauceLabs selenium server at https://ondemand.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] Spec started
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] [04:29:40] W/element - more than one element found for locator By(css selector, app-root h1) - the first result will be used
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] 
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0]   bookreader App
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0]     ✗ should display message saying app works
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0]       - Expected 'app works!' to equal 'APP WORKS!'.
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0]     ✗ should display message saying banner title
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0]       - Expected 'Banner title' to equal 'BANNER TITLE'.
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0]     ✗ should display message saying banner works
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0]       - Expected 'banner works!' to equal 'banner works!'.
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] 
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] **************************************************
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] *                    Failures                    *
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] **************************************************
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] 
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] 1) bookreader App should display message saying app works
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0]   - Expected 'app works!' to equal 'APP WORKS!'.
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] 
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] 2) bookreader App should display message saying banner title
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0]   - Expected 'Banner title' to equal 'BANNER TITLE'.
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] 
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] 3) bookreader App should display message saying banner works
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0]   - Expected 'banner works!' to equal 'banner works!'.
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] 
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] Executed 3 of 3 specs (3 FAILED) in 5 secs.
[MicrosoftEdge Windows 10 #81-0] [04:29:43] I/sauce - SauceLabs results available at http://saucelabs.com/jobs/d732c6621c7f4ccd9e8731c966cbb67a
```

At first, I thought it was because, with Edge, the returned response is "app works!" while with Chrome (or Firefox or Safari) the response is "APP WORKS!", but the problem also appears with a text in lower case.

Here is my protractor.sauce.conf.js file:

```
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;

var buildNumber = 'travis-build#'+process.env.TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER;

exports.config = {
  sauceUser: process.env.SAUCE_USERNAME,
  sauceKey: process.env.SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY,
  allScriptsTimeout: 72000,
  getPageTimeout: 72000,
  specs: [
    '../dist/out-tsc-e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.js',
    '../dist/out-tsc-e2e/**/*.po.js'
  ],
  multiCapabilities: [
    {
      browserName: 'safari',
      platform: 'macOS 10.12',
      name: "safari-osx-tests",
      shardTestFiles: true,
      maxInstances: 5
    },
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      platform: 'Linux',
      name: "chrome-linux-tests",
      shardTestFiles: true,
      maxInstances: 5
    },
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      platform: 'macOS 10.12',
      name: "chrome-macos-tests",
      shardTestFiles: true,
      maxInstances: 5
    },
    {
      browserName: 'chrome',
      platform: 'Windows 10',
      name: "chrome-latest-windows-tests",
      shardTestFiles: true,
      maxInstances: 5
    },
    {
      browserName: 'firefox',
      platform: 'Linux',
      name: "firefox-linux-tests",
      shardTestFiles: true,
      maxInstances: 5
    },
    {
      browserName: 'firefox',
      platform: 'macOS 10.12',
      name: "firefox-macos-tests",
      shardTestFiles: true,
      maxInstances: 5
    },
    {
      browserName: 'firefox',
      platform: 'Windows 10',
      name: "firefox-latest-windows-tests",
      shardTestFiles: true,
      maxInstances: 5
    },
    {
      browserName: 'internet explorer',
      platform: 'Windows 10',
      name: "ie-latest-windows-tests",
      shardTestFiles: true,
      maxInstances: 5
    },
    {
      browserName: 'MicrosoftEdge',
      platform: 'Windows 10',
      name: "edge-latest-windows-tests",
      shardTestFiles: true,
      maxInstances: 5
    }
  ],
  sauceBuild: buildNumber,
  directConnect: false,
  baseUrl: URL_TO_GITHUB_PAGE,
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 360000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
  beforeLaunch: function() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e'
    });
  },
  onPrepare: function() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter());
  }
};
```

And my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "bookreader",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test --code-coverage true --watch false && cat ./coverage/*/lcov.info | ./node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "build-gh-pages": "ng build --prod --base-href \"/bookreader/\"",
    "deploy-gh-pages": "angular-cli-ghpages --repo=https://GH_TOKEN@MY_REPOSITORY --name=USERNAME --email=EMAIL"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular-cli-ghpages": "^0.5.0",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-coveralls": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Does anybody have a suggestion? Any help would be much appreciated! Many thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

In the DOM, the text is printed as `app works!` and it is displayed in upper case with CSS.

Comment: First of all tnx for the good explained issue. When I look at my own tests I use with Protractor + Edge + Sauce Labs I also saw some difference in the returned text. I think the Edge WebDriver has an issue with returning the visual text. Can you verify in the DOM how the text printed, so is it printed as `example text` and manipulated with CSS to `EXAMPLE TEXT` If so, then I think this is an issue with the Edge WebDriver and you should log an issue [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/support/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! In the DOM, the text is printed as "app works!" and it is displayed in upper case with CSS.